# How can save the text of the label as an integer variable in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I need to save the changing text of my label as a variable, but if write the following code:

```
var warn = Int(self.dyn.text)
```

It says:

```
Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'
Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'
```

What code should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var warn = Int(self.dyn.text ?? "") ?? 0
```

You have to provide a default value, just in case it's not possible to make the cast to Int. You also have to make sure the text value is not nil.

Take a look at optional chaining and optional binding

Another approach is:

```
    if let dynText = self.dyn.text {
        if let warn = Int(dynText) {

            // warn is an available int variable here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: In second if condition you will get warning 'cast from string to unrelated type Int always fails'.

Answer (score 1):

2 way of doiing that

```
1: let warn = Int(self.dyn.text ?? "") ?? 0

2: let warn = Int(self.dyn.text!)!
```

Comment: Your second piece of code will crash if you don't have a valid number.

Comment: Yes you are right , but if you are sure that label always have value then you can use 2nd option otherwise 1st one preferable

Comment: The second line will crash if the label has no text.

Answer (score 1):

Good. Because String can be `"123"`  or `"Hello,world"` so it can be numeric or String text

When you use this 
`Int(String)` the initializer might fail, it returns an optional `Int`, rather than an `Int`

Example

```
let possibleNumber = "123"
let convertedNumber = Int(possibleNumber)
// convertedNumber is inferred to be of type "Int?", or "optional Int"
```

So you have to Unwrap it

Like that

```
   // unwrap text if TextField is not `!`  and then unwrap text when you convert to Int
    if let dynText = self.dyn.text , let warn = Int(dynText) {
       print(warn)
  }
```

Comment: `UITextField.text` is never `nil` though. You can just use `!`.

Comment: no problem , if we make sure it not nil no need to unwrap text

Comment: @Sulthan This is about a UILabel, not a UITextField. UILabel does not have the same guarantee.

Comment: @rmaddy so if UILabel is implicitly unwrapping with (!)  its text still optional because its (text) property is optional  .

Comment: @rmaddy I guess you are right. I never considered that someone could be reading the value of a `UILabel`.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish You mean "explicitly unwrapped with !". The `text` property of `UILabel` is optional and it can return `nil` so never force-unwrap it. But with `UITextField`, even though its `text` property is optional, it will never return `nil` even if you set it to `nil`. So that can safely be force-unwrapped.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, no one should be reading the value of a label but that is what is being done in the question apparently.